# When does pandas read_csv read blank values as 'nan' string?

Tags: python, pandas

## EDIT2 (SOLVED)

tl;dr Pandas is loading the blanks correctly as NaN. The issue is due to a function that processes the data.

Data:

```
In: df
Out: 
          name  column1
0  72944014961      NaN
1  81870301050      NaN
2  85266074963      NaN
```

It looks ok, but to make sure:

```
In: pd.isna(df['column1'])
Out: 
0    True
1    True
2    True
Name: column1, dtype: bool
```

Then, column1 gets transformed by the following function:

```
set_as_null = [None, 'NOT APPLICABLE', np.nan]
df['column1'] = df['column1'].map(lambda x: '' if x in set_as_null else '_'.join(str(x).lower().split()))
```

Which returns

```
In: df
Out: 
          name column2
0  72944014961     nan
1  81870301050     nan
2  85266074963     nan

In: pd.isna(df['column2'])
Out: 
0    False
1    False
2    False
```

This happens because of the fact that within pandas and Numpy np.nan != np.nan ([link](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/missing_data.html#:%7E:text=One%20has%20to%20be%20mindful%20that%20in%20Python%20(and%20NumPy)%2C%20the%20nan%27s%20don%E2%80%99t%20compare%20equal%5D)).

Using simple df.fillna('') with 'NOT APPLICABLE' handled by specifying na_values in pd.read_csv, as one of you suggested, solves the issue.

This problem has a learning value for myself, but I don't see the learning value of this post to the community. The np.nan != np.nan problem has already been answered in other questions, so I am going to delete this one.

### ORIGINAL PROBLEM

I am reading a csv file with

`ab = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(data_dir, f'{prefix}_ab.csv'), dtype={'name': str}, low_memory=False)`

For some reason, blank values (checked with a text editor) are loaded as 'nan' in string format.

EDIT1: I am aware that blanks are by default treated as NaN values by pandas and I am ok with that. However, in this case, they are loaded as 'nan' in string format, which makes both replace based on np.nan and .fillna('') not working.

So when I try to remove missing values using the code below, they are not detected:

```
set_as_null = [None, 'NOT APPLICABLE', np.nan]
(ab['column1'].map(lambda x: '' if x in set_as_null else x))
```

[image]

When I include 'nan' in set_as_null list, it obviously get replaced with '', but I am wondering why pandas reads blanks as string 'nan' in the first place (and not as NaN as it usually does)?

Comment: you need to use `.fillna()`

Comment: If not "NaN", then what value would you propose?   0?

Comment: @MarkLavin thanks for the answer, but you are missing my point. I've added EDIT1 above because it was probably not clear enough.

Comment: Show us a snippet your input data (post the data, not an image of the data). [mcve]. Anyway `pd.read_csv(..., na_values='nan')` should fix it, please confirm?

Comment: Because *you* did `dtype={'name': str}`. Just let it infer `object`

Comment: Also, `x in [None, 'NOT APPLICABLE', np.nan]` *would not work anyway*

Comment: @smci I've edited my post and provided the answer to the problem. It is not down to pd.read_csv, so I am going to delete the post. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Janek: ok, but you still haven't shown the **input** data i.e. a **3-line snippet of the input csv**. Without that, this is irreproducible, hence violates SO [mcve] requirement. (What was the encoding? ascii, utf8 or what? Were there perhaps invisible or nonbreaking whitespace characters that caused this? Does it only occur on some encodings? which?) Also, important to say which version(s) of pandas this occurs on. As a person who's debugged pandas and other issues for many years, just insisting that the columns are blank is not a testcase.

Answer (score 4):

Solution: tell `read_csv` that string 'nan' is an NA value:

```
pandas.read_csv(..., na_values='nan')
```

The [`na_values` arg](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html?highlight=na_values) can be a string or list of strings. So you could pass it `[‘<NA>’, ‘N/A’, ‘NA’, ‘NULL’, ‘NaN’, ‘n/a’, ‘nan’, ‘null’]`.

Then `.fillna()` will work.

Answer (score 0):

from: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/missing_data.html

As data comes in many shapes and forms, pandas aims to be flexible with regard to handling missing data. While NaN is the default missing value marker for reasons of computational speed and convenience, we need to be able to easily detect this value with data of different types: floating point, integer, boolean, and general object. In many cases, however, the Python None will arise and we wish to also consider that “missing” or “not available” or “NA”.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I meant a case when pd.read_csv reads blanks as 'nan' but in string format (so, once loaded, Python does not see it as a NaN, but as a string). Please see my EDIT1 above for the full clarification.